# Map entry key 9144667160333333333 becomes 9144667160333334000 in produced JSON

Tags: json, jersey, numbers, jax-rs

I'm using restygwt, jersey and building web app. If my resource sends map with a string as some entry key like `"9144667160333333333"`, I receive entry with a key `"9144667160333334000"` in method callback. If my resource sends string like `"a9144667160333333333"`, then I receive it correctly.

My resource looks like

```
    @GET
    @Path("/get/getpoints/{projectId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Map<String, String>> getAZPoints(@PathParam("projectId") BigInteger projectID) { ... }
```

Can you help me in solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the same problem here https://github.com/resty-gwt/resty-gwt/issues/119. As a solution, I send my number as a "a" + BigInteger and decode it on a client side.